# Why am I getting this Javascript error "connection is not defined"?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error:

```
connection is not defined   
document.getElementById("flashTest").sendValFromHtml(connection.value);
```

This is my code:

```
function submitCheck() {
    var hasConnection = document.getElementById("formTest").connection.value.length != 0; 
    var hasLocation = document.getElementById("formTest").location.value.length != 0;

    document.getElementById("connection").className = hasConnection ? "" : "invalid";
    document.getElementById("location").className = hasLocation ? "" : "invalid";

    if(hasConnection && hasLocation){
        document.getElementById("flashTest").sendValFromHtml(connection.value);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="formTest" name="formTest" method="post" action="">
    <fieldset class="form">
        <div class="connection">
            <label id="connection">Connection:*</label>
            <div class="textwrapper">
                <select name="connection">
                    <option value="">Select connection type</option>
                    <option value="dsl">DSL</option>
                    <option value="cable">Cable</option>
                    <option value="fibre">Fibre</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="location">
            <label id="location">Location*:</label>
            <div class="textwrapper">
                <select name="location">
                    <option value="">Select your location</option>
                    <option value="home">At home</option>
                    <option value="work">At work</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="postcode">
            <label>Postcode:</label>
            <div class="textwrapper">
                <input type="text" name="postcodeVal" id="postcodeVal">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="start clear"> 
        <input type="button" name="sendToFlash" id="sendToFlash" value="Start Test" onclick="submitCheck();" />

        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<embed src="/flash/speedtest.swf" id="flashTest" name="flashTest" width="540" height="320" allowscriptaccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  flashvars="jsfunc=pushResults&jsfunc2=showExtras" />
```

Comment: it doesn't appear connection is defined anywhere based on the code you've shown us

Comment: Can you post your HTML code also??

Comment: Where's `postcodeVal` defined?

Comment: @SunilKumarBM HTML has been added.

Comment: @AtesGoral I've just changed it to `connection` - you'll be able to see this in the newly added HTML codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, store the form as a local variable:

```
var form = document.getElementById("formTest");
```

Then use this local variable instead of querying the DOM multiple times:

```
var hasConnection = form.connection.value.length != 0; 
var hasLocation = form.location.value.length != 0;
```

Lastly, prefix `connection` with `form.`:

```
document.getElementById("flashTest").sendValFromHtml(form.connection.value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
var hasConnection = document.getElementById("formTest").connection.value.length != 0; 
var hasLocation = document.getElementById("formTest").location.value.length != 0;
```

with:

```
var hasConnection = document.getElementById("connection").value.length != 0; 
var hasLocation = document.getElementById("location").value.length != 0;
```

Comment: I tried your solution, now I'm getting `document.getElementById("connection").value is undefined` 

`var hasConnection = document.getElementById("connection").value.length != 0;`

Comment: the 2 `select` tags do not have the `id` attributes and so your cannot retrieve their values by using `document.getElementById()` function

Answer (score 1):

Change `connection.value` to:

```
document.forms.formTest.connection.value
```